# linking mono dynamically on android

Tags: c#, android, mono

I've compiled monosgen-2.0 for android successfully. When I link libmonosgen-2.0.a statically my app works fine.

But when I link  libmonosgen-2.0.so dynamically the app doesn't work.
The app doesn't come up at all and eclipse doesn't give me any information.
It just says Fatal Exception.

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := monosgen
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libmonosgen-2.0.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := F:/monoinstall-arm/include/mono-2.0/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hellodroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := monosgen

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I don't know what the problem is. But if I load the libmonosgen-2.0.so by dlopen and get it's methods using dlsym it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

how have you compiled the libmonosgen for android plase? I'm using the original mono build scripts, however the resulting libmonosgen-2.0.so is different from libmonosgen-2.0.so that is shipped with Xamarin Mono for Android applications (mainly required libraries differ). I'm using these configure options:

> --with-sgen=yes --disable-boehm --with-monodroid=yes --disable-mcs-build --with-sigaltstack=no --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi

This actually could answer your question as in static compilation, no additional dynamic libraries are needed as in dynamic linking.

Comment: well my libmonosgen differs from xamarin too. And I didn't need xamarin libraries. I just wanted to run C# .net code on android and I wrote lots of libraries which I needed myself.